# How to check value of column in spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, csv, indexing

I'm trying to write a condition based on whether a value in a column of a csv is a certain string.

This is my code, where I will execute some stuff based on whether the content of the cell in the column 'type' is a 'Question':

```
f = open('/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/harvard/edXresearch/snaCreationFiles/time_series/time_series.csv','rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')

for line in reader:
    if line['type'] == 'Question':
         print "T"
```

CSV:

The error I'm getting: `AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`

```
post_id thread_id   author_id   post_content  types       time     votes_up votes_down posters  
1           0           Jan     NULL          Question    3/1/12 10:45  5   1   Jan, Janet, Jack
2           0           Janet   NULL          Answer      3/1/12 11:00  2   1   Jan, Janet, Jack
3           0           Jack    NULL          Comment     3/2/12 8:00   0   0   Jan, Janet, Jack
4           1           Jason   NULL          Question    3/4/12 9:00   3   1   Jason, Jan, Janet
5           1           Jan     NULL          Answer      3/7/12 1:00   3   1   Jason, Jan, Janet
6           1           Janet   NULL          Answer      3/7/12 2:00   1   2   Jason, Jan, Janet
```

Comment: post more code please

Comment: Are you sure that's the code causing the problems?  That's the error you'd get if you had done `reader['type']` instead of `line['type']`.  Add `print type(line), repr(line)` to see what it really is.

Comment: When I write `for line in reader: print type(line)` it returns nothing

Comment: Where are you doing that? (Remember that you can only for-loop over `reader` once -- after that, you're at the end.)  Simply `f = open("/Users//etc")`, `reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')` and then `for line in reader: print type(line), repr(line)`.  Those four lines only.

Comment: could you provide a sample of your csv file that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the data you provided in a comma delimited CSV file, I then ran your code on the data you provided and got a `KeyError` for `type`, so I changed `if line['type']` to `if line['types']` and it worked.

My code:

```
import csv

f = open('test.csv','rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')

for line in reader:
    print line
    if line['types'] == 'Question':
        print 'The above line has type question'
```

My output:

```
{'thread_id': '0', 'posters  ': 'Jan', None: ['Janet', 'Jack'], 'post_id': '1', 'post_content': 'NULL', 'time': '3/1/12 10:45', 'votes_down': '1', 'votes_up': '5', 'author_id': 'Jan', 'types': 'Question'}
The above line has type question
{'thread_id': '0', 'posters  ': 'Jan', None: ['Janet', 'Jack'], 'post_id': '2', 'post_content': 'NULL', 'time': '3/1/12 11:00', 'votes_down': '1', 'votes_up': '2', 'author_id': 'Janet', 'types': 'Answer'}
{'thread_id': '0', 'posters  ': 'Jan', None: ['Janet', 'Jack'], 'post_id': '3', 'post_content': 'NULL', 'time': '3/2/12 8:00', 'votes_down': '0', 'votes_up': '0', 'author_id': 'Jack', 'types': 'Comment'}
{'thread_id': '1', 'posters  ': 'Jason', None: ['Jan', 'Janet'], 'post_id': '4', 'post_content': 'NULL', 'time': '3/4/12 9:00', 'votes_down': '1', 'votes_up': '3', 'author_id': 'Jason', 'types': 'Question'}
The above line has type question
{'thread_id': '1', 'posters  ': 'Jason', None: ['Jan', 'Janet'], 'post_id': '5', 'post_content': 'NULL', 'time': '3/7/12 1:00', 'votes_down': '1', 'votes_up': '3', 'author_id': 'Jan', 'types': 'Answer'}
{'thread_id': '1', 'posters  ': 'Jason', None: ['Jan', 'Janet'], 'post_id': '6', 'post_content': 'NULL', 'time': '3/7/12 2:00', 'votes_down': '2', 'votes_up': '1', 'author_id': 'Janet', 'types': 'Answer'}
```

The reason you have a key called `None` is because in the posters column the data is already comma delimited, therefore only the fist value in the column would be assigned the key 'posters'

I'm still not sure why you are getting an `attribute error`, but with a simple change to your code it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

python has a module to handle csv files in the standard library

https://www.google.com/search?q=python+csv

1st hit:

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check if your data has the header line by

```
has_header(sample)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue